# How to solve Gradle sync failed error (DefaultMavenFactory)?

Tags: android, maven, android-studio

I am trying to build project, but I get an error:

```
Gradle sync failed: Cause: org/gradle/api/publication/maven/internal/DefaultMavenFactory
Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)
```

I am using com.github.dcendents:android-maven-plugin:1.2 and Gradle 2.2.1 in project settings.

Here is full log. How to resolve it?

```
2015-10-07 12:10:57,789 [1857544]   INFO - ls.idea.gradle.GradleSyncState - Started sync with Gradle for project 'myproject'. 
2015-10-07 12:10:57,808 [1857563]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_71 
2015-10-07 12:10:57,813 [1857568]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_71 
2015-10-07 12:10:57,817 [1857572]   INFO - util.EmbeddedDistributionPaths - Looking for embedded Maven repo at 'C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\m2repository' 
2015-10-07 12:10:57,819 [1857574]   INFO - lij.tasks.impl.TaskManagerImpl - Updating issues cache (every 20 min) 
2015-10-07 12:10:57,863 [1857618]   INFO - .project.GradleExecutionHelper - Passing command-line args to Gradle Tooling API: [-Pandroid.injected.build.model.only=true, -Pandroid.injected.build.model.only.advanced=true, -Pandroid.injected.invoked.from.ide=true, --init-script, C:\Users\Смирнов\AppData\Local\Temp\asLocalRepo585.gradle, --init-script, C:\Users\Смирнов\AppData\Local\Temp\ijinit51.gradle] 
2015-10-07 12:10:59,019 [1858774]   INFO - .project.GradleProjectResolver - Gradle project resolve error 
org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not run build action using Gradle installation 'C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-2.4'.
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ResultHandlerAdapter.onFailure(ResultHandlerAdapter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.getResult(BlockingResultHandler.java:46)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildActionExecuter.run(DefaultBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.doResolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:188)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.access$300(GradleProjectResolver.java:65)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:360)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:332)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:225)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:97)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:65)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:41)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:49)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:51)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:138)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:124)
...
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jetbrains.ide.PooledThreadExecutor$1$1.run(PooledThreadExecutor.java:56)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Build file 'D:\Android\Projects\myproject\adapter\build.gradle' line: 12
A problem occurred evaluating project ':adapter'.
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultExceptionAnalyser.transform(DefaultExceptionAnalyser.java:77)
    at org.gradle.initialization.MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.transform(MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.java:47)
    at org.gradle.initialization.StackTraceSanitizingExceptionAnalyser.transform(StackTraceSanitizingExceptionAnalyser.java:30)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:108)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.getBuildAnalysis(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:97)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.configure(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:94)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.run(ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:49)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.DaemonHealthTracker.execute(DaemonHealthTracker.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:66)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:71)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.HintGCAfterBuild.execute(HintGCAfterBuild.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:246)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating project ':adapter'.
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:76)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl$1.run(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:148)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:156)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:39)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:26)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:34)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:487)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:85)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:47)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:35)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:129)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/gradle/api/publication/maven/internal/DefaultMavenFactory
    at org.gradle.api.plugins.AndroidMavenPlugin.apply(AndroidMavenPlugin.java:88)
    at org.gradle.api.plugins.AndroidMavenPlugin.apply(AndroidMavenPlugin.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.ImperativeOnlyPluginApplicator.applyImperative(ImperativeOnlyPluginApplicator.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.RuleBasedPluginApplicator.applyImperative(RuleBasedPluginApplicator.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.doApply(DefaultPluginManager.java:144)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.apply(DefaultPluginManager.java:112)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.applyType(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:113)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.access$200(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction$3.run(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.execute(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:136)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractPluginAware.apply(AbstractPluginAware.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.plugins.PluginAware$apply.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ProjectScript.apply(ProjectScript.groovy:34)
    at org.gradle.api.Script$apply$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at build_clpbuwva15tg9gbr3e2r9zgsb.run(D:\Android\Projects\myproject\adapter\build.gradle:12)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:74)
    ... 46 more
2015-10-07 12:10:59,020 [1858775]   INFO - .BaseProjectImportErrorHandler - Failed to import Gradle project at 'D:\Android\Projects\myproject' 
org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Could not run build action using Gradle installation 'C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-2.4'.
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ResultHandlerAdapter.onFailure(ResultHandlerAdapter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.getResult(BlockingResultHandler.java:46)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildActionExecuter.run(DefaultBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.doResolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:188)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.access$300(GradleProjectResolver.java:65)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:360)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:332)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:225)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:97)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:65)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:41)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:49)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:51)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:138)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:124)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$4.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:540)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$5$2.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:621)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:563)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:152)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:452)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:402)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:137)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$1.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:126)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:400)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jetbrains.ide.PooledThreadExecutor$1$1.run(PooledThreadExecutor.java:56)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Build file 'D:\Android\Projects\myproject\adapter\build.gradle' line: 12
A problem occurred evaluating project ':adapter'.
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultExceptionAnalyser.transform(DefaultExceptionAnalyser.java:77)
    at org.gradle.initialization.MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.transform(MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.java:47)
    at org.gradle.initialization.StackTraceSanitizingExceptionAnalyser.transform(StackTraceSanitizingExceptionAnalyser.java:30)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:108)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.getBuildAnalysis(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:97)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.configure(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:94)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.run(ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:49)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
...
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.DaemonHealthTracker.execute(DaemonHealthTracker.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:66)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:71)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.HintGCAfterBuild.execute(HintGCAfterBuild.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:246)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating project ':adapter'.
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:76)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl$1.run(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:148)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:156)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:39)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:26)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:34)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:487)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:85)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:47)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:35)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:129)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/gradle/api/publication/maven/internal/DefaultMavenFactory
    at org.gradle.api.plugins.AndroidMavenPlugin.apply(AndroidMavenPlugin.java:88)
    at org.gradle.api.plugins.AndroidMavenPlugin.apply(AndroidMavenPlugin.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.ImperativeOnlyPluginApplicator.applyImperative(ImperativeOnlyPluginApplicator.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.RuleBasedPluginApplicator.applyImperative(RuleBasedPluginApplicator.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.doApply(DefaultPluginManager.java:144)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.apply(DefaultPluginManager.java:112)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.applyType(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:113)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.access$200(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction$3.run(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.execute(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:136)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractPluginAware.apply(AbstractPluginAware.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.plugins.PluginAware$apply.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ProjectScript.apply(ProjectScript.groovy:34)
    at org.gradle.api.Script$apply$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at build_clpbuwva15tg9gbr3e2r9zgsb.run(D:\Android\Projects\myproject\adapter\build.gradle:12)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:74)
    ... 46 more
2015-10-07 12:10:59,022 [1858777]   WARN - nal.AbstractExternalSystemTask - Cause: org/gradle/api/publication/maven/internal/DefaultMavenFactory 
com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.LocationAwareExternalSystemException: Cause: org/gradle/api/publication/maven/internal/DefaultMavenFactory
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectImportErrorHandler.createUserFriendlyError(AbstractProjectImportErrorHandler.java:103)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.BaseProjectImportErrorHandler.getUserFriendlyError(BaseProjectImportErrorHandler.java:158)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.BaseGradleProjectResolverExtension.getUserFriendlyError(BaseGradleProjectResolverExtension.java:438)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.AndroidGradleProjectResolver.getUserFriendlyError(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:348)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.getUserFriendlyError(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:164)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:366)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:332)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:225)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:97)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:65)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:41)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:59)
...
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:124)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$4.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:540)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$5$2.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:621)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:563)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:152)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:452)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:402)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:137)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$1.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:126)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:400)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jetbrains.ide.PooledThreadExecutor$1$1.run(PooledThreadExecutor.java:56)

2015-10-07 12:10:59,023 [1858778]   WARN - radle.project.ProjectSetUpTask -  
2015-10-07 12:10:59,023 [1858778]   INFO - radle.project.ProjectSetUpTask - Cause: org/gradle/api/publication/maven/internal/DefaultMavenFactory

Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) 
2015-10-07 12:10:59,023 [1858778]   INFO - ls.idea.gradle.GradleSyncState - Sync with Gradle for project 'myproject' failed: Cause: org/gradle/api/publication/maven/internal/DefaultMavenFactory

Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) 
2015-10-07 12:10:59,063 [1858818]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Clearing symbols finished in 0 s. 
2015-10-07 12:10:59,064 [1858819]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Loading symbols finished in 0 s. 
2015-10-07 12:10:59,065 [1858820]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Building symbols finished in 0 s. 
2015-10-07 12:10:59,065 [1858820]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Saving symbols finished in 0 s. 
2015-10-07 12:12:11,707 [1931462]   WARN - inspections.IntellijLintClient - No projects found for [] 
2015-10-07 12:12:39,560 [1959315]   WARN - inspections.IntellijLintClient - No projects found for []
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solve this problem. It was happening because Android Studio can't install Gradle 2.2.1 and using Gradle 2.4 (already installed). I just run `gradlew.bat assembleDebug` command and then re-import this project again into Studio. Now it working well.

Answer (score 78):

I was also facing same issue few days back. I solved it by updating maven plugin version and gradle-maven-plugin version.
I updated plugin from

```
apply plugin: 'android-maven'
```

to

```
apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'
```

and gradle version from

```
classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-plugin:1.2'
```

to

```
classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.3'
```

Hope it solves your issue also

Comment: Thank you so much. Solved my problem

Comment: Solved my problem, Thanks

Comment: It's actually this line does the magic!!!
`classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.3'`

Comment: In my case this line solved the issue, plus some other lines. See my comment [here](https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook/issues/405)

Answer (score 1):

I also get into the similar issue because of the dependency `com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.4.1`.

To fix that we need to use the correct `gradle version` as mentioned [here](https://github.com/dcendents/android-maven-gradle-plugin#note-on-releases). As mentioned in that page I updated the `gradle version` in the `grade\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties` file to `2.14` like below.

> distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14-all.zip

Note: Also take care about the `plugin name`. I am using `apply plugin com.github.dcendents.android-maven`. Refer the below table to find yours.

For reference I am added the content in the [link](https://github.com/dcendents/android-maven-gradle-plugin#note-on-releases) below. `Dated 16-July-2016`

```
Plugin Version | Plugin Name | Dependency Information | Gradle Version 
1.0 | android-maven | com.github.dcendents:android-maven-plugin:1.0 | 1.8+ 
1.1 | android-maven | com.github.dcendents:android-maven-plugin:1.1 | 1.12+ 
1.2 | com.github.dcendents.android-maven | com.github.dcendents:android-maven-plugin:1.2 | 2.2+ 
1.3 | com.github.dcendents.android-maven | com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.3 | 2.4+ 
1.4.1 | com.github.dcendents.android-maven | com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.4.1 | 2.14+
```