# What is difference content://mms-sms and content://sms and database mmssms.db

Tags: android, sms, android-sqlite

I am programming one app similar SMS app native on android. I used content://sms to load sms and put into listview, but with more 1000 sms, it taked about 5s to load full sms. I think it too long time. I also search on the internet and find content://mms-sms but still don't try, another one is database mmssms.db I try write query on console use adb, it run very fast.

Should I use thing to load sms fast.

Comment: Basically, there are separate tables for SMS and MMS in the database stored in the `mmssms.db` file. Using `contents://sms` queries just the SMS table; `content://mms-sms` queries both. If you just care about SMS, use `contents://sms`.

Comment: @MikeM. if use contents:/sms , do you know query to get only sms of once thread_id ?

Comment: Check this library : https://github.com/EverythingMe

Comment: A simple example that returns all columns: if the ID is `threadId` - `getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://sms/conversations/" + threadId), null, null, null, null)`.

Comment: @MikeM. when have 2 thread_id 66, 66 and 1 thread_id 40. I want to ask query to get thread_id 40 and newest thread_id 66.

Comment: @AboHani Could you point project or give me small example. Thanks so much for help.

Comment: https://github.com/EverythingMe/easy-content-providers , Samples are in the project page, You can get the latest and all from Contacts/Messages/Logs .. everything .

Comment: @AboHani I download your project and import to Android Studio but fail and it notice: Error:Cause: org/gradle/api/publication/maven/internal/DefaultMavenFactory. How do I fix it?

Comment: *It's not my project :p , Here's already answered : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32988669/how-to-solve-gradle-sync-failed-error-defaultmavenfactory .